What is the recommended way to fetch data upon interaction?
Given that:

It is not recommended to fetch data on the client.
Server actions should not be used for data fetching, only mutations (create/update/delete).

What is the NextJS best practice to fetch data when a user chooses a sort option in a dropdown menu for a grid of cards?


You can use search params to do that.
I will give you an example of how to.
first create a new hook named useSearchParams
import { useSearchParams, useRouter, usePathname } from 'next/navigation'
import { useCallback } from 'react'

const useSearchState = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const searchParams = useSearchParams()
  const pathname = usePathname()

  const createQueryString = useCallback(
    (name: string, value: string) => {
      const params = new URLSearchParams(searchParams.toString())
      params.set(name, value)
      return params.toString()
    },
    [searchParams]
  )

  const push = (key: string, value: string) => {
    router.replace((pathname + '?' + createQueryString(key, value)))
  }

  return { push, createQueryString, get: searchParams.get, searchParams }
}
export default useSearchState

Your Sort Dropdown component should be implemented as a client-side component. This approach, as demonstrated in my project, ensures that whenever the sort value is modified, the page URL is dynamically updated to reflect the change. For instance, the URL might transform into something like http://.....com?sort=date_desc.
'use client'

export function IntegratedRecordsYearFilter() {
  const { push } = useSearchState()

  return (
    <Select onValueChange={(value) => push('yourSearchParamKey', value)}>
      <SelectTrigger className="min-w-36 md:min-w-64">
        <SelectValue placeholder="Filter records" />
      </SelectTrigger>
      <SelectContent>
        {years.map((year: number) => (
          <SelectItem key={year} value={String(year)}>
            <div className="flex items-center gap-2">{year}</div>
          </SelectItem>
        ))}
      </SelectContent>
    </Select>
  )
}

now you can access the search param key from your server component and refetch data when ever the search params change.
your server page component:
const ServerPage = async ({
  searchParams,
}: {
  searchParams: Promise<{ yourSearchParam: string }>
}) => {
  const { yourSearchParam } = await searchParams
  console.log(yourSearchParams)
  //your fetch function or DB call
  return <div>May Page</div>
}

